# Is there a way to utilize the [Authorize] attribute within a condition in the CSHTML of a razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-authorization

I'm working on a dotnet core/js application in which all of the frontend code including authentication page is produced with a JS framework where the bundled frontend is injected into a single Razor page. The frontend accesses all dotnet core logic from controller api endpoints. The authentication utilize bearer tokens and the [Authorize(role='whatever')] is used in several controllers.

For some reason, a single javascript plugin is injected into the app from the razor page. I basically need this plugin not to be visible before the user is authenticated. It's not a matter of "secret" content but the plugin just isn't useful before the user is authenticated. Is there a simple way for me to find out if the user is authorized within the CSHTML of the code as with the controller attributes? I've been searching around and found nothing very useful. Not an expert on c# or dotnet core (mostly been working on the frontend) and simplest possible solution would be appreciated. Don't know if I've missed any relevant information. If so, tell me!

Comment: Do you just want to check if the user is *authenticated* (i.e. logged in), if the user is in a specific role, or do you want to check against a specific authorization policy?

Comment: Only if the user is authenticated. Role is irrelevant :) Don't know much about the setup of policies. I'll dig into it if I have to.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the complexity of your condition, you have a few ways to authorize the user.

If you just want to verify that the user is *authenticated*, i.e. that they are successfully logged in, regardless of *who* the user is, then you can just check against [`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.isauthenticated?view=netstandard-2.0):

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>User is signed in.</p>
}
```

If you want to verify that the user [has a specific role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1), then you can also operate on the `User` principal object directly and just check for that specific role:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("role-name"))
{
    <p>User is in role <em>role-name</em>.</p>
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to utilize the full capability of the authorization system in ASP.NET Core, you can also inject the `IAuthorizationService` and authorize the user against a [configured authorization policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
@inject IAuthorizationService _authorizationService

@if ((await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "policy-name")).Succeeded)
{
    <p>User was authorized against policy <em>policy-name</em>.</p>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply! The first of your recommended solutions I've actually tried, however the User object is basically null which puzzles me as I though that would work given that the remaining authorization checks in the controllers work... Don't know where to go next from there without trying to figure out the whole authorization/authentication setup.

Comment: `User` should never be `null`, even for unauthenticated users. – This is a normal Razor page? And you have `app.UseAuthentication()` in your `Startup.Configure`?

Comment: Well, it is not a null reference but all parameters of User are null. I think it is a normal razor page. app.UseAuthentication() is configured.

Comment: Since the authentication is based on bearer tokens, might it be the case that only the authentication header of the REST api requests are used to determine who is authorized? This information is not available to the razor page... Any ideas?

Comment: _“all parameters of User are null”_ – That doesn’t sound right at all. The members of a `ClaimsPrincipal` cannot be null. And no, the system does not care _how_ the user is authenticated. There is no difference to a user authenticated by a cookie or by a bearer token. – However, it does appear very weird that you authenticate a user with a bearer token and still want to render content using Razor pages. Bearer authentication is mostly used for APIs and won’t work for views.

Comment: @poke Is there an API that enables manual challenging and checking on certain authentication schemes as in `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Scheme")]` in a similar manner as the `IAuthorizationService`?

Comment: @Beltway You can use the authentication service via `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Scheme")` which works similarly to how the `AuthorizeAsync` works (except just for authentication, not for authorization). Depending on the result, you can then start a challenge on the HttpContext for that scheme.